# How to call and pass data into a javascript function using MVC Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible and how do I call a js function passing in data using Razor Syntax. I have tried the following with failure.

```
onclick="Follow(@model => model.Id); return false;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass lambda expressions to methods that expect expressions. Like `Html.EditorFor`. Try `@this.Model.Id` instead. I would also suggest adding a check if `this.Model` is not null.